# IMacros: Extract text from site

Tags: web-scraping, imacros

I need to extract to clipboard activation link, link every registration changed.

[image: I need to extract to clipboard activation link, link every registration changed.]
HTML Code:

[image: HTML Code]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please elaborate on what you exactly need, so people can help you better.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this code:

```
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"(http://mctop.me/approve/\w+)" EXTRACT=$1
SET !CLIPBOARD {{!EXTRACT}}
```

Comment: Error -1200: parses "(http://mctop.me/approve/\w+)" - Unrecognized esc-sequence \w.

Comment: I gave a solution tested in 'iMacros for Firefox'. I don't work with 'Macros Browser' and 'iMacros for IE', nevertheless according to the [official wiki](http://wiki.imacros.net/SEARCH) can suggest the following version with doubled backslashes: `SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"(http://mctop.me/approve/\\w+)" EXTRACT=$1` .

Answer (score 0):

Error -1200: parses "(http://mctop.me/approve/\w+)" - Unrecognized esc-sequence \w.